# Promise Resolved Not Exiting

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I'm not sure why my function is not exiting after running. The code does not exit execution after resolving a promise.

I am using Firebase Admin SDK to send a message with the following:

```
var message = {
    data: {
        score: '850',
        time: '2:45'
    },
    topic: topic
};

admin.messaging().sendAll([message])
.then((response) => {
    // Response is a message ID string.
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
});
```

after printing to the console 'Successfully sent message:' the code console is still running and not return. What am I doing wrong?

For reference here is the signature of the firebase message send:

`send(message: admin.messaging.Message, dryRun?: boolean): Promise<string>;`

Comment: What do you mean by _"the code console"_? What is that? If you're seeing that `console.log()`, then your code has completed

Comment: Sorry I mean I see the console.log() message but the execution is still running. Is this expected I thought the execution should return or stop once the message is printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be something in the Firebase Admin SDK that is keeping the process from exiting.  You can force the process to exit when you're done by simply adding `process.exit(0)` to the end of the `then` callback, if that's when you want it to terminate.

If you think this behavior is a bug, you can file it on the [Firebase Admin SDK GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node).

Comment: If were you helped by this answer, it's customary on Stack Overflow to upvote and accept it as correct using the buttons to the left.